# Gradle printing numbers automatically

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am trying to learn gradle .In tutorial i found something like

```
 task count << {
    4.times { print "$it " }
}
```

On running the same i fount that its printing 0 to 3.How does that work.what does *"*$it"  means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Gradle by itself, but Groovy. As you may know, Gradle is  Groovy-based and the example above is the times-loop, which is the same as:

```
for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) 
    System.out.print(i);
```

in plain Java. And `$it` is a placeholder within the string for variable `it` which is the current index of the loop.

You can find a number of different groovy loops examples [here](http://grails.asia/groovy-for-loop-examples). And you have to read about closures [here](http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html).

Comment: so does it strictly needs to be only $it of can i also use something else like $pp or $x

Comment: @thinkingmonster within a string `$` is used to provide a placeholder. Out of the string it's just a `it` variable. If you have defined `pp` or `x` value, sure, you can use them to replace a placeholder within the string. Or you may define it as `task count << { x -> println x }`. `it` is just a default name

Comment: if i am using $xp in above example instead of $it then its throwing below error  * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':count'.
 > Could not find property 'xp' on task ':count'.    wondering what's so special about $it

Comment: @thinkingmonster you won't have it if you didn't define it. It is the default one and provided inside a loop by default. You may change it's name to xp, as i wrote in the previews comment

Comment: @thinkingmonster read about closures here http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html

Comment: that was really helpful